# Bootstrap UI - Typeahea iscreating unwanted UL tags

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an AEM based Angular SPA and used Bootstrap UI Library for Typeahead in various pages. There's an unwanted UL tag getting generated when checked a checkbox and is rendered as a small empty rectangle box.I used the following code to delete these unwanted UL tags. It is working in both Chrome and FIREFOX but not in IE11.
Here's the code in controller:

```
$scope.ClearBox = function(){
    var el = angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( 'ul' ) );
    angular.forEach(el, function(value, key){
        if(el[key].hasAttribute("id")){
            el[key].remove();
        } else {
            console.log("this has id"+ el[key].id);
        }
    });
};

<input Data-ng-change="ClearBox()" />
```

Comment: In IE11 what is the error that return?

Comment: I found the solution, i thought it has to do with QuerySelectorAll.. but the problem was with the "remove" method...I changed the code to

Comment: if(isIE){
                    console.log(el[key]);
                    alert(el[key]);
                    el[key].parentNode.removeChild(el[key]);
            }
            else{
                el[key].remove();
            }

Comment: thanks for responding Lorenzo!